# Cannot store data within a foreach loop, constantly loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to store specific data into an `array` so I can use it later.

I have tried storing the data within an array by key. But it just constantly loops far more times than it needs to. I set a condition that when the `row = "configurable"` (Which should be every 5th or 6th row) it unloads the data and restarts. So, I can put the data into the "Configurable" row and then start again.

I could be doing this completely wrong, but I cannot see another way around this. I have also tried placing the `"For"` loop in the Foreach, but it just gave me more problems with the looping.

(`$Ptype` is a value declared outside of this loop. It should occur every 4 - 6 rows)

```
$rowArr = 

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5.5
        [1] => sku123
        [2] => default
        [3] => simple
        [4] => testData4
        [5] => testData5
        [6] => testData6
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5.9
        [1] => sku456
        [2] => default
        [3] => simple
        [4] => testData4
        [5] => testData5
        [6] => testData6
    )
```

$rowArr continues for about 1000 rows. I want to get values [1] and [3], and to place them whenever the "if($ptype == 'configurable')" is met. Once this is done, I want to continue within the $rowData array and repeat until the if statement again.

So the output should be (I'll format this a bit):

[5.5, simple, 5.9, simple, ... , ...]

and then it should be removed once the if statement is met, to make room for the new values coming in.

```
   for ($i=1; $i < count($rowArr); $i++) {

    $Data[] = $rowArr[$i][1];
    $Data[] = $rowArr[$i][3];
    // without a "break;" here, it gets too many rows.
}


if($ptype == 'configurable'){

  $dataim = implode("," , $Data);
  echo $dataim . "\n";
  $dataim = "";

      // If I "die;" here, it fills the first row correctly, but it needs to get every row.
  reset($Data);
}
```

I have also tried (I have tried a lot of moving around breaks etc):

```
for ($i=1; $i < count($rowArr); $i++) {

    $Data[] = $rowArr[$i][1];
    $Data[] = $rowArr[$i][3];

    if($ptype == 'configurable'){

        $dataim = implode("," , $Data);
        echo $dataim . "\n";
        $dataim = "";

        reset($Data);
        break;
    } 

}
```

In Summary:

1. Store values [1] and [3] from another array
2. Once the [3] value is configurable, dump the data and start again in the array. continues indefinitely until rows are done.

Actual Result:

1. Just loops the first 2 values over and over again, not getting any other data if a break is implemented. Without the break in the `foreach` loop, it loops forever.
2. With a `"die;"` in the for loop, it gets the correct data, but only for the first row.

Comment: can you please post what values `rowArr` and your expected output

Comment: @RakeshJakhar I have edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using `Magento` and want to retrieve `simple` products of `configurable` products.

You have approach this as

```
$arr = [
 [5.5,'sku123','default','simple','testData4','testData5','testData6'],
 [5.9,'sku456','default','simple','testData4','testData5','testData6'],
 [5.9,'sku4561','default','configurable','testData4','testData5','testData6'],
 [5.5,'sku123111','default','simple','testData4','testData5','testData6'],
 [5.9,'sku456222','default','simple','testData4','testData5','testData6'],
[5.9,'sku456123','default','configurable','testData4','testData5','testData6'],
];
$data = [];
$records = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
 ($arr[$i][3] == 'configurable') ? ($records[$arr[$i][1]] = implode(',',call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data)) AND $data=[]) : ($data[] = [ $arr[$i][1],$arr[$i][3] ]);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($records);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
 [sku4561] => sku123,simple,sku456,simple
 [sku456123] => sku123111,simple,sku456222,simple
)
```

Comment: Yes! I am using Magento 2. Need to pull this data for an import.

I am getting this error with your code. It displays in the print_r though:
Warning: array_merge() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in ____ on line 204
PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in _____ on line 204

Comment: @user3623937 may be you are doing something wrong with the code

Comment: I cleaned up my import sheet (That was the problem)

Your solution worked perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code example the for loop continues until it reaches the end of $rowArr because there is no break condition.

In the second code example the loop ends prematurely, because once $ptype is 'configurable', the loop doesn't start again.

I did some testing with my own $rowArr and maybe the code below will help you.

```
$configurable = ["l", "w"];

$rowArr = array(
    ["not-configurable", "a", "b", "c"],
    ["not-configurable", "d", "e", "f"],
    ["not-configurable", "g", "h", "i"],
    ["configurable", "j", "k", "l"],
    ["not-configurable", "m", "n", "o"],
    ["not-configurable", "p", "r", "s"],
    ["configurable", "t", "u", "w"],
    ["not-configurable", "x", "y", "z"]
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($rowArr); $i++) {

    $Data[] = $rowArr[$i][1];
    $Data[] = $rowArr[$i][3];

    if(in_array($rowArr[$i][3], $configurable)) {

        $dataim = implode("," , $Data);
        echo $dataim . "\n";
        $dataim = "";

        reset($Data);
        array_splice($rowArr, $i, 1);
        $i = -1;

    } 
}
```

I hope I understood correctly what you're trying to achieve.